# How to set a default value for a custom field

Tags: api, developer, hooks

**EDIT: this is NOT working, at least in CiviCRM 5.24.2**
<del>**EDIT: this is done automatically by CiviCRM from 5.18+**</del>

I have a custom fieldset on Contributions that uses an option list. The option list has a default value set, but when contributions are created by non-UI processes (e.g. API) they do not have this default value; the field is empty/null/not there.

The fieldset is created by an extension. How could I ensure the default is set for all contributions?

Seems the options might be:

- Use [hook_civicrm_post](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_post) then use the API to make a call.
- Or could [hook_civicrm_pre](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_pre) be used for this? Can you set custom fields in this part of the process?
- or a horrible way would be to write an API job to somehow create default entries and run this by cron. Perhaps this might be necessary to set a default for existing contributions though?

Anyone done this? If so, how d'ya do it?

Comment: think you should update your answer too - perhaps insert at top of it

Comment: @petednz-fuzion erm, I did already!

Comment: odd. i must be tired. I see "EDIT: this is done automatically by CiviCRM from 5.18+" in your question but don't see equivalent in your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Used to work, before CiviCRM v5.18

Here's how I've opted to do it. Please do submit alternative answers if there's a better way.

Use the [civicrm_post hook](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_post) like this:

**Note that you need to replace `N` with your custom field's ID number**

```
function myext_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {

  if ($objectId && $op == 'create' && $objectName == 'Contribution') {

    // See if we have a field that belongs to the fieldset.
    $result = civicrm_api3('CustomValue', 'get', [
      'sequential' => 1,
      'entity_id' => $objectId,
      'entity_type' => "Contribution",
      'return.custom_N' => 1,
    ]);

    if ($result['count'] == 0) {
      // Create the default entry.
      $result = civicrm_api3('CustomValue', 'create', [
        'sequential' => 1,
        'entity_id' => $contribution_id,
        'entity_type' => "Contribution",
        'custom_N' => 'unknown',
        // custom_M ...
      ]);
    }

  }
}
```

Then when you create a Contribution, the defaults are properly set.

#### Interesting observations

My interest was in creating the default record when the contribution was created by the API. But I thought I'd look into how this works with using the UI too.

If you use the web UI to create a contribution then the code above gets in before the main process creates/sets the custom values. i.e. This is the order of things:

1. User creates a contribution record.
2. Contribution record created.
3. Our hook runs, no custom value exists so it creates the default record.
4. The user-entered values (inc. the defaults that were set up in the form) overwrite the default created by our hook.

The same process happens when you use the API to create a contribution but include values for the custom data also.

#### Why this no longer works

The above worked fine until sometime around CiviCRM version 5.18 at which point it stopped working. It stopped because during creation of a contribution this code would run, creating a custom data record, then the calling code would also try to create the same custom data record - causing a database error.

### Works, if you don't need to use phpunit (so, doesn't really work!)

I found that I could acheive what I had been trying to do as follows:

```
function myext_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {

  if ($objectId && $op == 'create' && $objectName == 'Contribution') {
     CRM_Core_Transaction::addCallback(
       CRM_Core_Transaction::PHASE_POST_COMMIT,
       'myfixercallback', [$objectId]);
  }
}
```

Then `myfixercallback` would do the same work. However, if you are using this then beware phpunit tests that use transaction interface: your code won't run until the test ends - which is too late!

**However!** <del>it seems that CiviCRM - at least from 5.18, possibly earlier, now properly creates default custom data. So this hack is simply not needed any more.</del> Sorry, certainly 5.24.2 does not do this.

### API Wrapper solution (tested with 5.24.2)

You can implement an API wrapper, but you need to implement it for both API3 and API4.

```
function giftaid_civicrm_apiWrappers(&$wrappers, $apiRequest) {
  if ($apiRequest['entity'] === 'Contribution' && $apiRequest['action'] === 'create') {
    $wrappers[] = new CRM_MyApiWrapperContributionCreate();
  }
}

// ... Implement the class ...

class CRM_MyApiWrapperContributionCreate implements API_Wrapper {

  public function fromApiInput($apiRequest) {

    if ($apiRequest instanceof Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction) {
      // APIv4
      $params = $apiRequest->getParams();
      if (empty($params['id']) && noneOfTheCustomFieldsAreDefinedApi4($apiRequest)) {
        $apiRequest->addValue('my_fieldset_name.my_field_name', '');
      }
    }
    if (empty($apiRequest['params']['id']) && noneOfTheCustomFieldsAreDefinedApi3($apiRequest)) {
        $apiRequest['params']['custom_1234'] = '';
      }
    }
    return $apiRequest;
  }

  public function toApiOutput($apiRequest, $result) {
    return $result;
  }
}
```

In this example

- `my_fieldset_name` is the custom fieldset, in which `my_field_name` is a field that has `''` as a default value, and an internal ID of 1234 which explains where `custom_1234` comes from.
- Rather than relying on setting a value to `''` you could look up the default value for a field, but if you're doing this for a specific solution you can do it this way to be more efficient.
- `noneOfTheCustomFieldsAreDefinedApi3` needs to scan the params for fields named `custom_N` where `N` is the known ID value of each of your fields. And `noneOfTheCustomFieldsAreDefinedApi4` needs to scan the params for keys beginning with `my_fieldset_name.`

Comment: As a follow-up, you don't need to use the API wrapper construct which is deprecated; instead you can just listen to the Symfony `\Civi\API\Events::PREPARE` event, which is cleaner. Please see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_apiWrappers/ for details

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @artfulrobot (thanks!), i have made a version of the code that use the definition of the custom field itself. If we have a default value, then force the creation of the field, otherwise, just ignore. Of course, it's probably a bit slower because we do some extra api calls, but it means we could change the defaults in the UI without changing the code.

```
function myext_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {

  if ($objectName == 'Contribution') {

    $result = civicrm_api3('CustomField', 'get', [
      'sequential' => 1,
      'return' => ["default_value", "custom_group_id", "name"],
      'default_value' => ['IS NOT NULL' => 1],
      // use your own custom group id
      'custom_group_id.id' => 1,
    ]); 
    if ($result['count']) {
      // use the first one (any will do because we know that we are in one custom group)
      $check_field = 'custom_' . $result['values'][0]['id'];

      // See if we have a field that belongs to the fieldset.
      $existResult = civicrm_api3('CustomValue', 'get', [
        'sequential' => 1,
        'entity_id' => $objectId,
        'entity_type' => "Contribution",
        'return.' . $check_field => 1,
      ]); 

      if ($existResult['count'] == 0) {
        // insert a new entry with defaults values
        $p = [ 
          'sequential' => 1,
          'entity_id' => $objectId,
          'entity_type' => 'Contribution'
        ];  
        foreach ($result['values'] as $row) {
          $id = $row['id'];
          $p['custom_' . $id] = $row['default_value'];
        }   

        // Create the default entry.                                                                                                        
        $result = civicrm_api3('CustomValue', 'create', $p);
      }   
    }

  }

}
```

I guess with a bit of extra effort, one could make a generic extension that works for any custom fields that attach to any entity type.

Comment: Nb. I think CiviCRM does this stuff now.

Comment: Ok, good to know thanks! Do you have any reference of the issue / pull request ?

Comment: No, I just noticed it at 5.18.

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this using [hook_civicrm_custom](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_custom).  This fires after the db write, which isn't ideal, but has a much simpler set of params than hook_civicrm_pre.

Comment: Does this call when Contributions are created? My db is not showing any record being written to the custom data table, which I think would imply that this hook would not fire (because the docs say "This hook is called AFTER the db write on a custom table" and no write has happened)?

Comment: Ah - I guess in my instance, I had other custom fields that were being written.  I don't think my solution will apply to your use case.